# Как исправить ошибку ssh подключения?

Tags: docker, ssh

При подключении SSH появляется ошибка:

```
    Connection id "0HM0GF577JND8" bad request data: "Invalid request line: 'SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7\x0D\x0A'"
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.BadHttpRequestException: Invalid request line: 'SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7\x0D\x0A'
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpParser`1.RejectRequestLine(Byte* requestLine, Int32 length)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpParser`1.GetUnknownMethod(Byte* data, Int32 length, Int32& methodLength)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpParser`1.ParseRequestLine(TRequestHandler handler, Byte* data, Int32 length)
```

Собираю и запускаю docker file:

```
 FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.0.0-preview7-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.0.100-preview7-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["WebApi/WebApi.csproj", "WebApi/"]
RUN dotnet restore "WebApi/WebApi.csproj"
COPY . .

WORKDIR "/src/WebApi"
RUN dotnet build "WebApi.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "WebApi.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y openssh-server
RUN mkdir /var/run/sshd
RUN echo 'root:screencast' | chpasswd
RUN sed -i 's/PermitRootLogin prohibit-password/PermitRootLogin yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config

# SSH login fix. Otherwise user is kicked off after login
RUN sed 's@session\s*required\s*pam_loginuid.so@session optional pam_loginuid.so@g' -i /etc/pam.d/sshd

ENV NOTVISIBLE "in users profile"
# RUN echo "export VISIBLE=now" >> /etc/profile

EXPOSE 22
RUN echo Finish install ssh»


ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApi.dll"]
```

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, Я использовал этот код в mac. Все работало хорошо

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, я просто представляю, что контейнеры работают не зависимо от системы запуска.  И как тогда сделать чтобы работало??

Comment: начните, для разнообразия, с подключения к ssh-серверу, а не к http-серверу.

Comment: Все разобрался. Но почему то порт для ssh закрыт. Щас с этим буду разбираться(